$C^1$ bijection $\Phi$ from an open set to another
Let $\Phi$ be a bijection of open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ onto another open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\Phi$ is $C^1$, i.e. $\Phi$ is continuous on $O$ and each partial derivative is $n$ times differentiable for each of the $n$ coordinates. If $E \subset U$ is measurable, show that $\Phi(E)$ is measurable.
There are a couple tools that come to mind when I see this problem. For one, we know that if $L$ is a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then if $E$ is measurable, so also is $L(E)$. Another tool that comes to mind is the idea that a set is measurable if and only if $E$ differs from an $F_\sigma$ (or $G_\delta$) set by a set of measure zero.
Any help or hints on this would be greatly appreciated!


A $C^1$ map is locally Lipschitz (mean-value theorem).
Locally-Lipschitz maps (where the dimension of the target is higher than the domain) send measure-zero sets to measure-zero sets (first reduce to the case of a Lipschitz map, and then note that if you have a cover by rectangles whose total measure is $<\epsilon$, then the Lipschitz condition allows you to control the size of the images of these rectangles)
A set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue-measurable if and only if it is the union of a measure zero-set with a $\sigma$-compact set. So, under a locally-Lipschitz map, the $\sigma$-compact set is mapped to a $\sigma$-compact set (simply by continuity), while the measure-zero set is sent to a measure-zero set, so the union is Lebesgue-measurable.

So, to summarize:

If $A\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue-measurable, and $f:A\to\Bbb{R}^m$ is locally-Lipschitz with $m\geq n$, then $f(A)$ is Lebesgue-measurable.

So, the part about $\Phi$ being a bijection is superfluous.
